# Is there a way to create a subscription to another user's mailbox using Graph API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I've gone thorugh the official Graph API documentation, and from what I've gathered, there is no direct way to create a subscription to another user's Outlook mailbox using the Microsoft Graph API, to keep track of incoming mails/messages, but is only possible for the signed-in user's mailbox.
Could I be given any insights on whether there's a way to do the aforesaid task and if its documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

If your using delegate permissions than that's correct, you can only subscribe to the signed in user's mailbox. If you use Application permissions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-share-messages-folders

> Note that those two permissions do not support subscribing to change notifications on items in shared or delegated folders. To set up change notification subscriptions on messages in a shared, delegated, or any other user's mail folder in the tenant, use the application permission, Mail.Read.

Then it will work okay. You can do Delta's on a shared folder eg https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/shared@mailbox.com/mailfolders/inbox/messages/delta and then poll it at intervals .